# Can I get a male Thunderbolt to female USB 3.0 adapter?

Tags: thunderbolt

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro that has now 1 terabyte of storage, but want to connect a external hard drive via the fastest connection possible. It didn't come with USB 3.0 but 2x USB 2.0 and Thunderbolt port. Can I get a male Thunderbolt to female USB 3.0 adapter?

Comment: The 2011 MacBook Pro has a thunderbolt port.

Answer (score 1):

The [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) port on your MacBook Pro is already faster than [USB 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.0) so the fastest possible connection of an external storage device would be to attach a Thunderbolt drive via the Thunderbolt port.

Note that Thunderbolt is a faster interface than a hard disk can accept or push data so for top speed you will either need a RAID configured for speed or an SSD drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can find now @ amazon or ebay http://www.ebay.com/itm/Thunderbolt-Port-to-USB-3-0-Super-Speed-Hard-Disk-Drive-Adapter-Dongle-for-Apple-/141776189587

Answer (score 0):

You can simply buy a Thunderbolt external hard drive like this [durable and portable](http://www.filmtools.com/lacie-rugged-thunderbolt-usb-3-0-1tb.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjw5MGxBRDiuZm2icXX2-sBEiQA619bq2DzKI2TZFw4LTYzs39BTlT1MK-MXSx8xHc9Amos6_8aAuZ58P8HAQ) one from LaCie. Be aware that these drives tend to be more expensive, but by the time you've bought a USB3.0 to Thunderbolt adapter and hard drive, you're better off going for the native Thunderbolt drive with USB3.0 connectivity as well.